# How correct create aliases when join many tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create a SQL query. I need to join many tables for my analytics

```
SELECT 
      asutNbd_violations.IncidentTypeID
      ,asutNbd_violations.IncidentID
      ,asutNbd_violations.ViolationDate as Date_NAR
      ,asutNbd_violations.BrigadeEnterpriseID
      ,asutNbd_violations.ViolationID as ID_SP_NAR,

      incidents.IncidentDate,
      incidents.RouteID,

      incidents.PersID,
      -- incidents.CasseteID,

      incidents.MIPersID 

     ,routes_personal.RouteID
      ,routes_personal.PersRegID
      ,routes_personal.RoutePostID
      ,routes_personal.BeginDate
      ,routes_personal.EndDate
      ,routes_personal.RouteDate



     ,personal_registration.EnterpriseID

      --,personal_registration.DateFrom 
     , CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) < 1 THEN 'group_0to1y'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) < 4 THEN 'group_1to3y'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) >= 4 AND DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) < 8 THEN 'group_3to8y'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) >= 8 AND DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) < 12 THEN 'group_8to12y'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) >= 12 AND DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) < 20 THEN 'group_12to20y'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(yyyy, personal_registration.DateFrom, getdate()) >= 20 THEN 'group_20y'
        ELSE NULL 
      END AS DateFrom
      ,personal_registration.DateTo
      ,personal_registration.TabNum
      ,personal_registration.IsDetached
      ,personal.LastName
      ,personal.FirstName
      ,personal.PatrName
      ,personal.CurrEnterpriseID  as KOD_DEPO
FROM 
    asutNbd_violations 
INNER JOIN 
    personal_registration AS PR5 ON incidents.PersID = PR5.[PersID]
INNER JOIN 
    personal ON personal_registration.[DateTo] = personal.[CurrDateTo]
             AND personal_registration.[TabNum] = personal.[CurrTabNum]
INNER JOIN 
    incidents ON asutNbd_violations.CasseteID = incidents.CasseteID
INNER JOIN 
    routes_personal ON incidents.RouteID  = routes_personal.RouteID
INNER JOIN 
    routes_personal ON [report_routesIssue].[RouteDate] = routes_personal.[RouteDate]
INNER JOIN 
    incidents ON [report_routesIssue].[RouteDate] = incidents.IncidentDate
```

but when I run it, I get these errors:

> Message 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
>   The multi-part identifier "incidents.PersID" could not be bound.
>
> Message 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
>   The multi-part identifier "personal_registration.DateTo" could not be bound.
>
> Message 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   The multi-part identifier "personal_registration.TabNum" could not be bound.
>
> Message 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The objects "routes_personal" and "routes_personal" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

I join the same tables several times.

I think the matter in aliases. I just don't know how correct put it.

Can you help me look at my query and suggest how insert aliases. All i can see is that problem in personal_registration table

Comment: You are joining with predicates on tables that haven't been included in the join yet - your first join is `inner JOIN personal_registration AS PR5 ON incidents.PersID = PR5.[PersID]` but at that point you haven't joined on `incidents`. Move this join `inner JOIN incidents ON asutNbd_violations.CasseteID = incidents.CasseteID` underneath the `FROM` - also if you are joining multiple times you need to provide an alias for the additional joins `incidents as incidents1` for example

Comment: @Charleh, ok i will try

Comment: If you give a table an alias (and you should), you must use that alias to reference the columns in it. For example, you must use PR5.DateTo rather than  personal_registration.DateTo. And for the love of future generations, **BE CONSISTENT**. You capitalize in a random fashion. Don't clutter your code with brackets as identifier delimiters when they are not needed. Datediff does not do what you seem to think - the case expression should be tested thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need table aliases for all tables, especially those mentioned multiple times in the `FROM` clause. Those aliases then need to be used throughout the query.

You have some suspicious things in the `FROM` clause:

- `routes_personal` is referenced twice.
- `report_routesIssue` is not referenced at all.  I think the second `routes_personal` should be this reference.
- `incidents` is referenced twice.  The second joins only on the date, which seems quite dangerous.  I would guess this is an error.

Fixing these things, you end up with a query that looks more like:

```
SELECT av.s.IncidentTypeID, av.IncidentID, av.ViolationDate as Date_NAR
       av.BrigadeEnterpriseID, av.ViolationID as ID_SP_NAR,
       i.IncidentDate, i.RouteID,
       . . .   -- and so on
FROM asutNbd_violations av JOIN
     personal_registration pr
     ON i.PersID = pr.[PersID] JOIN
     personal p
     ON pr.[DateTo] = p.[CurrDateTo] AND
        pr.[TabNum] = p.[CurrTabNum] JOIN
     incidents i
     ON av.CasseteID = i.CasseteID JOIN
     routes_personal rp
     ON i.RouteID  = rp.RouteID JOIN
     report_routesIssue rri  -- LOOKS LIKE AN ERROR HERE
     ON rri.[RouteDate] = rp.[RouteDate] /* JOIN
     incidents rri_i
     ON rri.[RouteDate] = i.IncidentDate */
```

I don't know if the second `incidents` reference is desired.